# php - use loop to repeat steps n number of times

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I hope I can explain this well. I'm working on a project relating to airline booking. I have a shopping cart with the user's selected route(s) and the date.
For each passenger, and each flight, I want to cycle through the same steps - get the name of the passenger, and assign them a seat.

```
$flightIds = array_keys($this->cartElements);

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($flightIds);$i++){

            $flightid = $flightIds[$i];

            for($j=1;$j<=$this->cartElements[$flightid]['count'];$j++){
               $route = $this->cartElements[$flightid]['route']; 
               $date = $this->cartElements[$flightid]['date'];
               genInputView($route, $date, $j);

function genInputView($route, $date, $passNumber) {

?>

<form action="controller.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="selectSeats">
   <table>
     <tr><td>Please enter the name for Passenger $j on the $route flight:    </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="custName"></td></tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="route" value="<?php $route ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php $date ?>">
         <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Continue"></td><td></td></tr></table>
</form>
```

This is outputting the table in a single page instead of what I was hoping for - go to a new page, deal with one customer, then repeat for every other customer.

Could somebody please suggest how I could do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question , rephrase it and add an example to the desired output.

Comment: So, the user might have selected the NY to LA flight, and the LA to NY flight, 2 passengers on each. In this case I will want the code to follow the same steps 4 times, go to a new screen and get the user to input the passenger name, then repeat. But it is currently outputting 4 text boxes and 4 submit buttons on the same page. Does that make sense?

Comment: I see at least two options: First, you could put all four boxes on one site but seperate them so far from each other that a click on "next" will forward the user to the next anchor on the site further down below, which should equal a new site. Second, use AJAX and put the html content for each customer/deal/page thingy into a single div, changing the content according to user action.

Comment: Also, there must be an error in your code. The `for`-loop has an opening bracket but no closing one. getInputView() has no closing bracket but a php-closing-bracket. Is $j and $route in the table really working that way? And while you're at it, maybe you could indent the table at the bottom correctly. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Sorry - I'm new to all of this. Yes, I missed some of the code when copying it in. I'm using i and j to loop twice - once for each individual flight in the purchase, and once for each passenger on that flight. Thank you for your feedback - I think just keeping it all on the same page should work. I'll give that a go.